# CVE-2021-26691 on php:7.4-apache docker

Tags: docker

Iam using php:7.4-apache as my base image, which throws CVE-2021-26691 (while doing AQUA SCAN). How should i fix this? I tried changing my php version thinking it would pick up right apache version.

Any lead regarding shall be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a custom image based on php:7.4 and install apache 2.4.48 on it or use a multi stage docker file with apache >= 2.4.48 and php 7.4